# me to resolve below error trying to fine tune roberta model for NER

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, named-entity-recognition

Help me to resolve the below error trying to fine the roberta model for NER. Im using base model and trying to fine tune on my data.
import torch
import json
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from transformers import RobertaForTokenClassification, RobertaTokenizer
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss

```
            model_name = "roberta-base"
            tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
            model = RobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

            class NERDataset(Dataset):
                def __init__(self, texts, entities, tokenizer):
                    self.texts = texts
                    self.entities = entities
                    self.tokenizer = tokenizer

                def __len__(self):
                    return len(self.texts)

                def __getitem__(self, idx):
                    text = self.texts[idx]
                    entities = self.entities[idx]

                    # Extract labels directly from entities
                    #labels = [label["label"] for entity in entities for label in entity]
                    labels = [label["label"] for entity in entities for label in entity if isinstance(label, dict) and "label" in label]

                    

                    # Tokenize input text
                    encoding = self.tokenizer(
                        text,
                        return_tensors="pt",
                        truncation=True,
                        padding="max_length",
                        max_length=512,
                        labels=labels
                    )

                    return {
                        "input_ids": encoding["input_ids"].squeeze(),
                        "attention_mask": encoding["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
                        "labels": encoding["labels"].squeeze() if labels else None
                    }

            # Load data from JSONL file
            def load_data_from_jsonl(file_path):
                data = []
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                    for line in file:
                        try:
                            example = json.loads(line)
                            data.append(example)
                        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                            print(f"Error decoding JSON on line: {line}")
                            print(e)
                return data

            # Example usage:
            jsonl_file_path = "./admin.jsonl"
            data = load_data_from_jsonl(jsonl_file_path)

            # Extract texts and entities from your data
            texts = ["John is good boy", "Goole is software"]
            entities = [
                [
                    {"label": "Person", "name": "John"},
                    {"label": "Location", "city": "New York"}
                ],
                [
                    {"label": "Organization", "name": "Google"},
                    {"label": "Date", "year": "2023"}
                ]
            ]

            # Create an instance of your custom dataset
            dataset = NERDataset(texts=texts, entities=entities, tokenizer=tokenizer)

            # Use the dataset in the Trainer
            training_args = TrainingArguments(
                output_dir="./output",
                num_train_epochs=3,
                per_device_train_batch_size=16,
                evaluation_strategy="epoch",
            )

            trainer = Trainer(
                model=model,
                args=training_args,
                train_dataset=dataset,
                # ... other Trainer arguments ...
            )

            trainer.train()
```